# JSON Null Poiner Exception

Tags: android, json, api, nullpointerexception

I got such a very strange problem. I already created weather application which using this [API](https://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=fe1c9cd3fd2d4b189c010010172505&q=Paris&days=5). Problem is that, when i am calling "CONDITION" object,than i am getting a null pointer exception.But when i am calling another object,than everything is fine! Its weird. During 2 weeks this API worked fine,but starting from yesterday, not. Can anyone explain me,why it is like that, and what i have to do. Because application is already finished, and i am making the another one, and i don't want to rewriting this application just because of that problem.

I put my response in another application, to check maybe the problem was in my application,not in the API. Here is the code..

```
API CLASS:

public interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET("/v1/current.json?key=fe1c9cd3fd2d4b189c010010172505")
    Call<Weather> getForecastWeather(
            @Query("q") String cityName
           // @Query("days")Integer days
    );
}
```

CONTROLLER CLASS:

```
public class Controller {

    static final String BASE_WEATHER_URL = "https://api.apixu.com/";


    public static WeatherAPI getApi(){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_WEATHER_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        WeatherAPI weatherAPI = retrofit.create(WeatherAPI.class);

        return weatherAPI;
    }
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY CLASS:

```
mWeatherAPI = Controller.getApi();

        mWeatherAPI.getForecastWeather("Paris").enqueue(new Callback<Weather>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Weather> call, Response<Weather> response) {
                String description = response.body().getCurrent().getCondition().getIcon();
                Log.e("TAG", "description: " + description);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Weather> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.e("TAG", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: You would need to add the code where you parsing the json response.

Comment: No stacktrace, no code => no answer (because it's impossible to, unless there's some crystal ball involved)

Comment: @Sac added. Check the code,pls

Comment: @TarasStavnychyi Put the stack trace too , your crash logs.

Comment: log cat please..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add `OkHttpClient` to your `Retrofit`:

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
 Retrofit retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(yourBaseUrlString)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .retrofitBuilder.client(okHttpClientBuilder.build()).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the json Object whether u created or not.